# NSManagedObject Can't conform to protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need a shared interface for a NSManagedObject and a regular NSObject. In Objective-c,I could use a protocol to achieve that. But in Swift i get this runtime error. Any Solution?    Thanks in advance!

```
protocol Product {
    var code: String { get set }
    var sp: String { get set }
}

class Stock: NSManagedObject, Product {
    @NSManaged var code: String
    @NSManaged var sp: String
}
```

> Error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
> "__TFC11YellowPages5Stockg2spSS", referenced from:
> __TFC11YellowPages5Stockm2spSS in Stock.o
> "__TFC11YellowPages5Stockg4codeSS", referenced from:
> __TFC11YellowPages5Stockm4codeSS in Stock.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Have you tried adding @objc to the beginning of your protocol?

Comment: I've just tried this but it still doesn't work.@DanielT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me. Try it for yourself and see if it works:

```
class MyEntity: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var testAttribute: String
}

@objc
protocol MyProtocol {

    var testAttribute: String { get set }
}

extension MyEntity: MyProtocol { }

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let myContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        let entity: MyEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyEntity", inManagedObjectContext: myContext) as MyEntity
        foo(entity)
        println(entity.testAttribute)
    }

    func foo(var object: MyProtocol) {
        object.testAttribute = "bar"
    }
}
```

The below also worked, but I think the above is a better way to do it:

```
@objc
protocol MyProtocol {

    var testAttribute: String { get set }
}

class MyEntity: NSManagedObject, MyProtocol {

    @NSManaged var testAttribute: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let myContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        let entity: MyEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyEntity", inManagedObjectContext: myContext) as MyEntity
        foo(entity)
        println(entity.testAttribute)
    }

    func foo(var object: MyProtocol) {
        object.testAttribute = "bar"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.When I put the extension and NSManagedObject class code
together in a swift file, it still shows the same error.But If I move the extension code to another file.It works well.So weird

Comment: @objc wouldn't work for me due to CLLocationCoordinate2D. What did work was simply moving my protocol to the extension class that is auto generated via CoreData - before I had it in the class (which is also auto generated)

Comment: There is a problem in these approaches when you try to express in the protocol a relation between two managed objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

> When you mark a member declaration with the dynamic modifier, access
>   to that member is always dynamically dispatched using the Objective-C
>   runtime. Access to that member is never inlined or devirtualized by the compiler.

```
class Stock: NSManagedObject, Product {
    @NSManaged dynamic var code: String
    @NSManaged dynamic var sp: String
}
```

More on this [here](https://www.lesstroud.com/dynamic-dispatch-with-nsmanaged-in-swift/)