# CoreData type passed to function

Tags: swift, core-data, methods

Say I have three different managed objects. Each type of object has identical properties. I would like to write a method that will accept any one of the three objects and assign values to their properties.

```
let car = Car(context: context)
let boat = Boat(context: context)
let plane = Plane(context: context)

getDistanceTraveled(vehicle: car)

func getDistanceTraveled(vehicle: NSManagedObject) {
    let newVehicle = vehicle as? Car //Instead of Car I want to cast this as the type being passed in.
    newVehicle.distanceTraveled = 43
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good use of a protocol.

Comment: But then wouldn't I have three nearly identical versions of the same method? The method was my attempt to reduce duplicate code since all three types would call the function one after the other.

Comment: No, you would have one function that takes a reference to the protocol.

Comment: I guess don't understand how that would work. Off to learn more about protocols...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, following the composite reuse principle (composition over inheritance), I would suggest using a protocol for a problem like this e.g.

```
protocol Vehicle {
    var distanceTraveled: Float { get set }
}

struct Car: Vehicle  {
    var distanceTraveled: Float
}

struct Boat: Vehicle {
    var distanceTraveled: Float
}
```

Then pass a `Vehicle` into your function:

```
func getDistanceTravelled(vehicle: Vehicle) -> Float {
    return vehicle.distanceTraveled
}
```

However, I think this is more complex than what is described above as the `Car`, `Boat` and `Plane` objects are managed by Core Data and are a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

Whilst there are ways to deal with this, e.g.

- [NSManagedObject Can't conform to protocol in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203722/nsmanagedobject-cant-conform-to-protocol-in-swift)
- http://lesstroud.com/dynamic-dispatch-with-nsmanaged-in-swift/

I would instead suggest creating a `Vehicle` parent entity in Core Data that contains the shared properties, then making `Vehicle` the parent entity of your other entities car, plane etc.

e.g.

[Vehcile entity screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK1e0.png)

[Car entity screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psu2A.png)

[Plane entity screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/562at.png)

You can then pass a `Vehicle` managed object into your function like so:

```
func getDistanceTravelled(vehicle: Vehicle) -> Float {
    return vehicle.distanceTraveled
}
```

This goes against the composite reuse principle mentioned above, but I think due to the nature of core data this could be one of those scenarios where inheritance wins.

Comment: I like this answer because I had a parent entity already and it makes perfect sense. And as a bonus, now I get to learn about something called the composite reuse principal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A *swifty* solution is a protocol extension constrained to `NSManagedObject`

```
protocol TravelDistance {
    var distanceTraveled: Float { get }
}

extension TravelDistance where Self : NSManagedObject {
    func getDistanceTravelled(vehicle: TravelDistance) -> Float {
        return vehicle.distanceTraveled
    }
}
```

All `NSManagedObject` subclasses which conform to `TravelDistance` can use this method.

Comment: Apparently, I have more to learn about protocols, so I'm sure I'll be revisiting this answer at some point. Thanks!